# Website theme suddenly showed white space on right side

Tags: html, css, wordpress

website is http://peekawoo.com and there is a white space showing on right side. I've checked other posts here on stackoverflow, and also tried {margin:0;padding:0;} to no avail. I also tried firebug (i am very new to this), but I can't find which one is causing it - I cannot see any width that is not 100%.  It wasn't like this before. i just noticed the white space just today after changing the background and link color on wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrappers are messed up, however you can remove

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

attribute in the body tag for a quick fix.

Comment: @Mizuki : This works..I was going to post this answer..

Comment: hello! appreciate your replies. I just removed it, but sadly, still the same T.T

Comment: You still have it set as overflow-y: scroll within the body {} tag.

Comment: @Bonius ah. I checked the css folder and it has 2 css files. The other one has the same name but with "min.css" I checked and it has the code. Thanks so much everyone. Now I can sleep peacefully. ^_^

Comment: Ah yes, I would simply use the developer CSS while developing, then minify it upon release. Saves a lot of headaches (like the one you just encountered) :)